# how can I align the button and the text inline

Tags: html, css

I want to align the button and the text in the same line.

```
<div class="oferts">
    <div class="container" style="line-height: 300px; text-align: center;">
        <h1>Bucura-te de ofertele noastre alaturi de familia ta <button class="oferts-button"><a href="#">Vezi toate beneficiile terapiilor</a></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
button {
    background: transparent;
    color: #666;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    transition: border .3s ease-in;
}
button:hover {
    border: 1px solid #909090;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
button a {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.oferts-button a {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}
.oferts-button:hover {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.oferts {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    height: 300px;
    background:url(../img/back.jpg) center no-repeat;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you answering your own question?

Comment: somone ask for the css.... and I could't edit the post because was to much code.

Comment: To get faster answer always create jsfiddle for css issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the vertical-align css property on both elements:

```
container {
    line-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;    
}
container > h1,
container > h1 a {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: ^ Mark the answer, Razvan.

Comment: If you decide to accept my answer @Razvan (and any else future question), please click the "check icon" on the left side of the number surronded by top/bottom arrows, on the left of the (choosen) response.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x4618tr4/)

**HTML** Removed h1 tags, as was not ending and didn't even found in css

> NOTE: Used font-size - 32px because h1 tag = 32px

```
<div class="oferts">
    <div class="container">  
        Bucura-te de ofertele noastre alaturi de familia ta 
        <button class="oferts-button">
            <a href="#">Vezi toate beneficiile terapiilor</a>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** Add this class to your CSS

```
.container
{
    line-height: 300px; 
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:32px;
}
```